# How to solve error in eclipse: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse

This is my first java project that I got off of the internet.  I know I have made some mistakes, so I tried to fix it in a copied version and it still didn't run.  Can anyone tell me how to solve this error with my project?  I have tried looking at the other solutions and cant seem to find anything that fixes it for me.  My computer is a mac.  Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: click on the writing to see the screenshot of my project

Comment: Please go through the [tour] and do take a look at the [help] section as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, so that your questions and answers will be better making your future experiences here better.

Comment: Please don't use "screen shots". Post your code as text so we can copy and paste the code and analyze it.

Comment: your `main` method signature is missing static needs to be changed to `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: Why are you using static inner classes and putting your main method inside of them? Solution: don't do this.

Comment: You have a subclass of type static within a class with a different name than the file name.